# как изменить цвет кнопки при нажатии?

Tags: qml

как изменить цвет кнопки при нажатии ?

Пытаюсь при нажатии кнопки чтоб кнопка меняла свет, (типо зажатая "простейшая анимация").

Если не прописывать  `background: Rectangle` то цвет меняется, но мне ненравится базовый цвет хочу его поменять

```
    // увы в этом варианте я так и несмог реализовать "зажатие"
    Button {
        text: qsTr("линия")

        background: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 100
            implicitHeight: 40
            color: "#bde0ff"
            border.color: "#bde0ff"
            radius: 2
        }

        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }


    Button {
         text: qsTr("радиус")
         background: Rectangle {
             implicitWidth: 100
             implicitHeight: 40
              // вот тут не работает вообще
              color: control.pressed ? "#bde0ff" : "#ccccff"
              border.color: "#bde0ff"
             radius: size / 2
         }

         onClicked: {
             //Qt.quit();
         }
    }

    // это вариант из интеренета "просто мусор"
    Button {
        id: goToParenFolder
        text: "Hi"
        flat: true
        Material.foreground: "#bde0ff"
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем разобрался

забыл выдать id (ссылку) на обьект

```
Button {
            id: button3
            text: qsTr("радиус")
            background: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 100
                implicitHeight: 40
                color: button3.down ? "#ccccff" : "#bde0ff"
                border.color: button3.down ? "#ccccff" : "#bde0ff"
                radius: 2
            }
```

от сюда нашёл пример  https://yiyibooks.cn/779068092/Qt_571_API/qtquickcontrols2/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html

---

*аж 2 часа на это потратил ишлее всего перелистал и пиндосские форумы*